# How to use timestamp in AWS Timestream

Tags: amazon-timestream

I have a table with a time field and I am trying to select between 2 timestamps which are in the format:

"2020-10-10 09:00:00.000000000"

I have tried some functions listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/date-time-functions.html) but without success.

Edit: The data is there, as seen in the picture. But the example shows using 7 days ago instead of passing a timestamp.

[image]

Comment: Please check this page on how to ask a question on StackOverflow and improve your chances of getting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
The query you wrote is correct and it looks like it has returned results. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @MaFF I explained the picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the key word `TIMESTAMP` before the string representation of the timestamp to declare a timestamp type:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 09:00:00'
```

To filter using an interval you can use keyword `BETWEEN` or any [comparison operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/comparison-operators.html):

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM my_database.my_table
WHERE
    time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 09:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 11:00:00'
```